# input text, strip fake path, output in input text

Tags: javascript, file, input, strip

So I have recently "made" (taking bits and pieces from guides) a custom button  for an input file form, but also with a little text displayer to the right. Now, in chrome, as a safety precaution, they have removed the path to the image - which is obviously logical. However, there is a possibility to remove these tags and just output the file name.

Now I have a clue how to do it, in theory, but I have no idea how to ACTUALLY do it. It's probably easy for the guys who knows this, but I have no idea. Would be amazing if you'd knew and told me!

This is the stripping thing I guess would work

```
 file = path.split('\\').pop();
```

http://i.gyazo.com/ccccb44e7550475acb0cbccf4de20d0e.png

this is the HTML

```
<table style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <td style="width: 18%">
        <label class="fileUpload">
            <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" />
            <div class="button-speed-menu-browse">
                BROWSE..
            </div>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="uploadFile" class="field-path-input" placeholder="Choose PNG file" disabled/>
    </td>
</table>
```

Now for the javascript (which is at the bottom).

```
document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
};
```

Comment: so you wanted to show only the filename?? instead of `fakename/filename.doc`

Comment: @SAQUEIB That's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you can get the image name using `split()`

**Try it**

```js
document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value.split("\\").pop();
};
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <td style="width: 18%">
    <label class="fileUpload">
      <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" />
      <div class="button-speed-menu-browse">
        BROWSE..
      </div>
    </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input id="uploadFile" class="field-path-input" placeholder="Choose PNG file" disabled/>
  </td>
</table>
```